# New ATL COM project in Visual C++ 2010 Express: Missing Template

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, shell-extensions

I have a feeling that this is a pretty silly and basic question, but I've been struggling with this for a tad too long today.  I am attempting to make a shell extension for Windows following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens) guide (as well as several others that I have stumbled upon, but that one is the most notable).  The issue is that they all start off saying "Run the AppWizard and make a new ATL COM program."  However, these are the only project wizards I have in my Visual C++ 2010 Express.

[image: Visual C++ 2010 Express Project Wizards]

Where can I find this magic project template?  Even [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d30daewt(v=vs.100).aspx) seems to think I should already have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK frameworks MFC, ATL possibly others are not part of the Express edition, to have them you need one of the non-free versions. [but there are some interesting links](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/102538/)

Comment: How stupid of me... According to the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express), "Applications using either MFC or ATL are not supported by Visual C++ Express".  You are absolutely correct.  DANGIT!